# Find median of a list of values in Access 2010 - SQL or VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, median

I have a list of time-intervals (in seconds) between consecutive datetime-stamped records in a dataset in Access 2010. I want to find the median time interval for each Animal on each Date. 
Please can someone tell me how to go about this - either in SQL or VBA?

Example data:

```
Animal      Date        Time_interval
1           18/07/14    1
1           18/07/14    18
1           18/07/14    100
1           18/07/14    121
1           18/07/14    156
2           18/07/14    14
2           18/07/14    35
```

(I also have a field for Time, not included here to keep things simple)

Thanks very much!!

Comment: I am fairly sure you will need VBA UDF for median eg http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Aggregate_Median_%28UDF%29

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/A_2529-Median-Mode-Skewness-and-Kurtosis-in-MS-Access.html

Comment: I have tried adding this DMedian module to my database: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/how-do-i-calculate-median-in-access_10.html. I then wrote this query, SELECT Query3.TRANScDate, Query3.AnimalID, DMedian("CountOfCaptureID","Query3") AS Expr1
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.TRANScDate, Query3.AnimalID;
which seems to work for finding the median for the whole dataset, but how do I find the median for each Animal on each Date.

Comment: Sorry I have changed the field names a bit, which might cause confusion - but TRANScDate refers to Date, AnimalID to Animal and CountOfCaptureID is Time_interval.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query with to compare the 2 date/time entries using the DateDiff function.

Here is the setup for DateDiff:

```
DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])
```

From what I understand, create a new query and add a field like this:

```
median_time_interval: DateDiff ("s", Date, Time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Signatures are discouraged here. If you have a personal or business website you can mention it in your profile, but please do not append it to each of your posts unless it is a direct link to a specific page supporting that particular answer.